# LocalRepositoryNotAccessibleException Could not create local repository at /testartifacts/m2repository

Tags: maven, azure-devops, jmeter, continuous-integration, maven-3

I'm running a CI pipeline in Azure DevOps with a Maven build step called "Download provided dependency JARs".

This step was working before, however it's suddenly giving me this error:

```
org.apache.maven.repository.LocalRepositoryNotAccessibleException: Could not create local repository at /testartifacts/m2repository
```

I'm also getting a warning:

```
##[warning]Could not parse the effective POM.
```

This is what it looks like in DevOps:
[image]

I've set it to clean the working directory before the build is run, but this didn't help.
[image]

From what I've read, it seems to be a permissions issue.

Shouldn't the build agent already have permissions?

I appreciate your help.

This is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>au.com.mycompany.perfunittests</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapplication</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <profiles>
        <!-- Load Test -->
        <profile>
            <id>profile.loadTest</id>
            <!-- Test will only be chosen when -DtestType=load -->
            <activation>
                <!-- Test will be chosen when property testname is not supplied, i.e. the default -->
                <property>
                    <name>!testname</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <testname>loadtest.myapplication</testname>
                <isbenchmarktest>false</isbenchmarktest>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <!-- Benchmark Test for Common -->
        <profile>
            <id>profile.benchmarkTest.Common</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>testname</name>
                    <value>unittest.myapplication.common</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <testname>unittest.myapplication.common</testname>
                <isbenchmarktest>true</isbenchmarktest>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <!-- Benchmark Test for Configuration -->
        <profile>
            <id>profile.benchmarkTest.Configuration</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>testname</name>
                    <value>unittest.myapplication.configuration</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <testname>unittest.myapplication.configuration</testname>
                <isbenchmarktest>true</isbenchmarktest>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <!-- Benchmark Test for Dashboard - note this is legacy Dashboard API calls -->
        <profile>
            <id>profile.benchmarkTest.Dashboard</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>testname</name>
                    <value>unittest.myapplication.dashboard</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <testname>unittest.myapplication.dashboard</testname>
                <isbenchmarktest>true</isbenchmarktest>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <!-- Benchmark Test for Management -->
        <profile>
            <id>profile.benchmarkTest.Management</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>testname</name>
                    <value>unittest.myapplication.management</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <testname>unittest.myapplication.management</testname>
                <isbenchmarktest>true</isbenchmarktest>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <!-- No need to run deploy lifecycle -->
        <maven.deploy.skip>true</maven.deploy.skip>

        <!-- No need to create a JAR -->
        <jar.skipIfEmpty>true</jar.skipIfEmpty>
        <maven.install.skip>true</maven.install.skip>

        <!-- Run in perftest env unless overridden using -Denv -->
        <env>perf</env>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>mycompanyproject-visualstudio.com-maven</id>
            <url>https://mycompanyproject.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/maven/maven/v1</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <jmeterVersion>5.0</jmeterVersion>
                    <!-- JMX file for unittests lives in the same directory as pom.xml -->
                    <testFilesDirectory>${project.basedir}</testFilesDirectory>
                    <testFilesIncluded>
                        <jMeterTestFile>${testname}.jmx</jMeterTestFile>
                    </testFilesIncluded>
                    <!-- Need to save in CSV format for lightning plugin -->
                    <resultsFileFormat>csv</resultsFileFormat>
                    <!-- Don't append timestamp to JTL file, so lightning can find it more easily -->
                    <testResultsTimestamp>false</testResultsTimestamp>
                    <!-- Don't stop the test on a failure -->
                    <ignoreResultFailures>true</ignoreResultFailures>
                    <propertiesUser>
                        <env>${env}</env>
                        <url.myapplication>perfweb.myapplication.com</url.myapplication>
                        <unittest.path.resources>${project.basedir}</unittest.path.resources>
                        <unittest.path.testdata>${project.basedir}/data</unittest.path.testdata>
                    </propertiesUser>
                    <!-- Additional output JTL format for lightning plugin -->
                    <propertiesJMeter>
                        <httpclient.reset_state_on_thread_group_iteration>false</httpclient.reset_state_on_thread_group_iteration>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.successful>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.successful>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.label>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.label>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.time>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.time>
                    </propertiesJMeter>
                    <customPropertiesFiles>
                        <file>${project.basedir}/${testname}.threadgroups.conf</file>
                    </customPropertiesFiles>
                    <!-- Additional libraries (mostly) from jmeter-plugins.org -->
                    <jmeterExtensions>
                        <artifact>au.com.mycompany:timinglistener:0.2-SNAPSHOT</artifact>
                        <artifact>com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2</artifact>
                        <artifact>com.opencsv:opencsv:4.1</artifact>
                        <artifact>com.sumologic.plugins.log4j:sumologic-log4j2-appender:1.7</artifact>
                    </jmeterExtensions>
                    <jMeterProcessJVMSettings>
                        <xms>2048</xms>
                        <xmx>2048</xmx>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>-Dunittest.path.logs=${project.build.directory}/jmeter/logs</argument>
                            <argument>-Dunittest.testname=${testname}</argument>
                            <argument>-Dlog4j.configurationFile=file://${project.basedir}/log4j2.xml</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </jMeterProcessJVMSettings>
                    <downloadExtensionDependencies>true</downloadExtensionDependencies>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>uk.co.automatictester</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-lightning-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>lightning</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <mode>verify</mode>
                            <!-- Lightning XML definition file lives in the same directory as pom.xml -->
                            <testSetXml>${project.basedir}/${testname}.xml</testSetXml>
                            <!-- Test output JTL file written to target/jmeter/results/<testname>.csv -->
                            <jmeterCsv>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/results/${testname}.csv</jmeterCsv>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: @user7294900 I'm using Maven to build a JMeter project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all I had to do was change the Agent Specification from ubuntu-18.04 to vs2017-win2016.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks you ran your pipeline on self-hosted agent. Or you configured the maven to retrieve the dependencies from the local repository(in `mvnsettings.xml`, or `.m2/settings.xml` ). If you ran your pipeline on self-hosted agent. You can check if the local repo `/testartifacts/m2repository` exists.

If you run your pipeline on cloud agents, you need to find which setting files configured the the local repo, And remove the localRepository.

Then you might need to use [Maven Authenticate task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/maven-authenticate?view=azure-devops) to provides credentials for Azure Artifacts feeds and external Maven repositories.

Add Maven Authenticate task at the top of your pipeline. And select your azure maven feed from the `Feeds` dropdown list

[image]

This task will store the credentials on a temp settings.xml file(**with feed name as the server id**, see below) on the agent, which will be used to authenticate the maven repository in the following maven task.

[image]

Noted: The **repository id** you specified in your pom.xml file(ie. see below highlighted) should be the same with the **name of your azure artifacts maven feed**. Or it will still fail to authenticate the feed in the follow maven task. for the **server id** in the temp settings.xml file created above is the **feed name**.

[image]

Comment: I added the authentication step as you suggested.
I changed mycompanyproject-visualstudio.com-maven in pom.xml to just mycompany since that's the name of the feed (a feed called maven was also available but I only selected mycompany).
I saved the pom.xml and pushed to source control, then ran the build but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @DavidKlempfner Were you running your pipeline on self-hosted agent. It looks like the maven is looking for a local repository, but fail to find it, or the agent service doesnot have to permission to access. See above update

Comment: Turns out all I had to do was change the Agent Specification from ubuntu-18.04 to vs2017-win2016. It works now. Thanks for your help.